# How can i clear web view on switching from one class to another?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, viewcontroller

i have a webview in my detailviewcontroller to load html formatted local text to show details, detailviewcontroller also has a back button, that when pressed i want to clear the web view so that i other detail will show it will be clear to avoid a flick of reloading.

in DetailViewController i have-

```
- (IBAction)backbuttonClicked:(id)sender {
[_delegate backFromDetailView];
}

-(void)clearWebView{
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];

[self.detailWebView loadHTMLString:@"<html><head></head><body></body></html>" baseURL:nil];
[self.detailWebView reload];
}

-(void)changeDetailViewTextTo:(NSString *)text{

NSString *htmlString=[HTMLString getHTMLStringForString:text];
[self.detailWebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
}
```

and in mainviewcontroller i have

```
-(void)backFromDetailView{
((DetailViewController*)_detailsViewController).delegate=nil;
[((DetailViewController*)_detailsViewController) clearWebView];
}
```

Still flicking the text, please help.

Answer (score 0):

you can load your webview with the default blank page.

```
[self.detailWebView loadRequest:
[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]]];
```